# APP_INITIALIZER failing test cases

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, angular-test

I am using APP_INITIALIZER to make some API calls, everything is working fine but adding

```
 { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: MyProviderFactory, deps: [MyService], multi: true }
```

in app.module.ts failing my test cases.
Here is my app.module.ts file

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
// tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length

import { MyService } from './services/my-provider.service';

export function MyProviderFactory(provider: MyService) {
  return () => provider.getdata();
}


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: AppComponent }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [ MyService,
              { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: MyProviderFactory, deps: [MyService], multi: true }
            ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the error

```
"message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nFailed: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
```

Also how to test APP_INITIALIZER in the app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi & welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at [ask] and consider updating your question. You have provided little to no useful information to help others help you.

Comment: Thank you, I am new here and will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

As your error says, your factory is not returning a stream (observable, promise, array or iterable). Instead, you are returning a function.

Assuming your `MyService.getdata()` returns one of those, you can just return it `return provider.getdata()`.

Comment: Thanks, is there any that we can test ``` { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: MyProviderFactory, deps: [MyService], multi: true }```